# Is cocycle condition necesarry for coassociativity of coproduct and why is it called "cocycle condition"?

Tags: proof-writing, terminology, hopf-algebras

Let $\Delta_0$ and $\Delta$ be coproducts related by
\begin{equation}
\Delta h = \mathcal F \Delta_0 h \mathcal F^{-1}
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal F \in H\otimes H$ is Drinfeld twist and $h \in H$ is just an element of Hopf algebra.

The coproducts should be coassociative, i.e. 
\begin{equation}
(\Delta_0 \otimes 1)\Delta_0h=(1 \otimes \Delta_0)\Delta_0h
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(\Delta \otimes 1)\Delta h=(1 \otimes \Delta)\Delta h
\end{equation}

Using $\Delta h = \mathcal F \Delta_0 h \mathcal F^{-1}$ with those two relations yields that

\begin{equation}
\left[
(1 \otimes \mathcal F)(1 \otimes \Delta_0)\mathcal F
\right]^{-1}
\left[
(\mathcal F \otimes 1)(\Delta_0 \otimes 1)\mathcal F
\right]\equiv X
\end{equation}

and its inverse commute with any $(\Delta_0 \otimes 1)\Delta_0 h = (1 \otimes \Delta_0)\Delta_0 h \in H \otimes H \otimes H$.

Does this mean that $X$ has to be proportional to the unity? If so then

\begin{equation}
(\mathcal F \otimes 1)(\Delta_0 \otimes 1)\mathcal F = \lambda
(1 \otimes \mathcal F)(1 \otimes \Delta_0)\mathcal F
\end{equation}

where $\lambda$ is ordinary nonzero number.

Also, will $\lambda$ then necessarily be one? If so, then this is a cocycle condition:
\begin{equation}
(\mathcal F \otimes 1)(\Delta_0 \otimes 1)\mathcal F =
(1 \otimes \mathcal F)(1 \otimes \Delta_0)\mathcal F
\end{equation}

It is obvious that cocycle condition is sufficient condition for coassociativity of $\Delta$ if $\Delta_0$ is coassociative. But is it also necessary condition?

And why is it called "cocycle condition"?

Comment: «it has to be proportional to the unity»? What **it**? In any case,$H$ could be commutative, and it that case you are not going to be able to conclude anything from something commuting with something else!...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I've clarified what is **it**. Also, if $H$ is commutative, then this is a trivial case because then $\Delta h = \mathcal F \Delta_0 H \mathcal F^{-1} = \Delta_0 h$, i.e. twisting does nothing.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez It is now defined in the above formula as $\left[
(1 \otimes \mathcal F)(1 \otimes \Delta_0)\mathcal F
\right]^{-1}
\left[
(\mathcal F \otimes 1)(\Delta_0 \otimes 1)\mathcal F
\right]$, you've probably missed it.

Comment: t is called a cocycle condition because $F$ is a cocycle in a certain cohomology theory exactly when that condition is satisfied. The problem is that the cohomology theory is only defined under certain conditions (commutativity or cocommutativity, for example)

Answer (score 0):

First to say something about why this is a "cocycle condition": The class of quasi-Hopf algebras (coassociativity up to a 3-cocycle) is stable under Drinfeld twists (by 2-cocycle). Chapter 6 of [1] describes how these 2 and 3-cocycles can be enhanced to the so-called non-abelian cohomology.

The paper [2] I found an interesting result related to your first question: For a given 3-cocycle $\Phi$, the authors introduce the notion of a $\Phi$-*cocycle* as an element $F\in H\otimes H$ for which your $X$ is equal to $\Phi$. For such elements, Proposition 3.2 the Drinfeld twist of $H$ by $F$ is a quasitriangular Hopf algebra.
Because of this Proposition, I think $\Phi$ is *not* necessarily proportional to $1$ as otherwise the theory of $\Phi$-cocycles would be useless.

It would be nice to have a concrete counterexample. Did you check the original Quantum Group examples by Drinfeld concretely?

[1] Majid, S. Cross product quantisation, nonabelian cohomology and twisting of Hopf algebras. Generalized symmetries in physics (Clausthal, 1993), 13--41, World Sci. Publ., River Edge, NJ, 1994

[2] Gurevich, D.; Majid, Shahn. Braided groups of Hopf algebras obtained by twisting. Pacific J. Math. 162 (1994), no. 1, 27--44